# Create Order status code 400 - Server Error

Tags: bluesnap

I'm trying to build a simple payment flow using Bluesnap. Currently I've been able to capture the users billing information using Hosted Fields, and then saved it to a "Shopper" in bluesnap. Now I'm trying to use the same Shopper to create an order (https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/create-order), but I can't get it to work.

I'm sending this:

```
<order>
  <ordering-shopper>
    <shopper-id> 
      --Shopper ID--
    </shopper-id>
    <web-info>
      <ip>127.0.0.1:61106</ip>
      <remote-host>www.merchant.com</remote-host>
      <user-agent>Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; X11)</user-agent>
    </web-info>
    <fraud-info>
      <fraud-session-id>1234567890</fraud-session-id>
    </fraud-info>
    <authorized-by-shopper>true</authorized-by-shopper>
  </ordering-shopper>
  <cart>
    <cart-item>
      <sku>
        <sku-id>2425735</sku-id>
      </sku>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
    </cart-item>
  </cart>
  <expected-total-price>
    <amount>15.00</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
  </expected-total-price>
</order>
```

Using a POST-request to BLUESNAPDOMAINPATH/services/2/orders

The only response I get is a status code 400 with the body containing "Server Error"

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root xml element is missing the namespace:

```
<order>
```

Should be:

```
 <order xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! I thought I was able to skip that attribute ;)